# Partition Hard Drive for use with Time Machine

Tags: macos, partitioning, time-machine

Is it possible to partition a hard drive in two and use one partition for Time Machine and the other for other uses? I am running Mac OS X 10.6.5 if it makes any difference.

***EDIT***: For clarification for future references: I am wishing to do this with an external hard drive.

Comment: I assume you already know this but this servely limits time machine's potential as a backup utility.

Comment: @Jaips: And why is that?

Comment: @Mr. Man: I'm under the assumption that you'll be partitioning an external drive for this purpose. Jaips might be under the assumption that you're interested in partitioning your internal drive.

Comment: @fideli: Yes, I am partitioning an external. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use the TM partition for data. TM puts backups in the folder `Backups.backupdb`. Ignore it and you're good. Only drawback of mixed use I have experienced: Deleting backups to get temporarily more disk space for storage is much easier when you can just delete a partition.

Comment: +1 for Daniel. TM backups are just normal folders, you can share the partition with other data. It is a bit tricky to delete the backups (you have to launch the TM application for that), but the only reason to want to partition is if you want a non-HFS+ partition on that disk as well (for Windows for example). Also, TM will eat up all free space on that partition, which could be a minor pain.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. I am using the other partition for an Ubuntu install. So the folder method would not work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely possible. Use Disk Utility, make the two partitions, and use the Mac OS X Extended (Journaled) filesystem for the partition you wish to use for Time Machine.

Comment: Just to clarify, just Mac OS X Extended for the Time Machine partition? And not Mac OS X Extended (Journaled)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Journaled. Basically, some people like to use FAT32 as the filesystem for external drives and that won't work for Time Machine.

Comment: Does this mean Time Machine will backup the internal Mac HD AND the partition for data on the external?